# Spring Reactive Proxy server for file operation on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, netty, project-reactor, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm building a proxy server that streams large files from clients (iOS, web etc) to S3. I'm planning to use Spring reactive with Netty. I'm catching up with Netty and reactive architecture and so far it looks very promising. Does anyone of you has solved something like this before? If yes, can you please share some pointers or a GitHub URL for a starter project that will be great.

Few questions:

Is this possible to do with my current tech stack? I think it is. But wanted to get feedback.

With Netty and reactive architecture, chunks of data will be coming in an async fashion, how do I make sure I send the packet in sequence to S3?

Also, does AmazonS3 client supports reactive file operations using their Java SDK? If not then probably I will need to directly call their API using Spring reactive WebClient.

I understand this question is not to the point and very broad. The intent here is to find if anyone has solved something like this and if they can provide some tips.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With upcoming AWS SDK 2.0, you should be able to use reactive file operation with S3 as it would call subscribe on the publishing stream you pass to it.